# Was my approach to negotiating reasonable?

Tags: salary, negotiation, relocation

I received an offer from one well established Company which I admire. This offer requires relocation to another Province and the offer is not as pleasing in comparison to my own package and there is no indication mentioned for relocation assistance.

I wrote them a letter which I sent this Monday (15/10/2018) being polite though appreciating the opportunity and thereafter I went to the point of asking them for room of improvement in the package and referring to my current package, I have years of experience in the field and qualifications obtained.

I mentioned that an increase of 10 - 20% would be appreciated in the request, (not sure though if that's too much). I also asked them if there is any assistance they can provide for relocation.

I have not received feedback as yet and I'm panicking already, I just made a follow up to the person I sent email to, just to check if she has received my email and she replied yes, and that she has forwarded email to the Compensation office.

How long should I wait?

Was my approach reasonable?

Answer (score 9):

> a letter which I sent this morning

So you literally just sent it and you're expecting an instant reply?

These things take time and consideration within a company. They need to weigh up the costs and whether your skills are worth your offer. Plus these requests and conversations have to go through multiple departments before even coming to a decision.

I personally don't think that you should have followed up on the original E-mail so quickly after sending a negotiation offer. These types of things can take days.

Stop panicking, there's plenty of time. This will give you time to consider whether you want to consider taking the offer if the company does not increase by 10-20% and what you are going to do otherwise. She should wait at least a few days

Answer (score 5):

Sending an email like that only makes sense if you are able to reject the offer. Especially if you are looking for as much as 10-20% more money, which is a lot.

It's not clear from your question whether you are prepared not to accept the offer if the salary is not increased.

They shouldn't take offense, although I guess cultural factors may play a role. In the US or most Western Europe renegotiation of salary is a normal thing. As we don't know where you are based, we can't tell you whether it's normal there.

Comment: Asking for more money is harmless, and may result in more money.  It makes sense to at least try to negotiate, even when the applicant would accept the original offer.